# How can I use webcam on fuerte?

Tags: ros, frame, libuvc-camera, camera, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte. I want to get frame from webcam. I try to install camera driver. I plan to use **ucv_cam** driver but its documentation says that

> This package is no longer actively maintained.

So I want to try **libucv_camera** . libuvc_camera documentation has 3 ros version(groovy, hydro, indigo), not fuerte.  How can I use camera on fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212730/how-can-i-use-webcam-on-fuerte?/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This just means nobody takes care for it, further development, bugs ... etc.

If you want to use fuerte I guess, I think it does not matter if you use that package.
In your case, I would upgrade your own packages to use catkin instead of hanging around with the old distribution.
If that is not possible, you will have to backport all newer packages to fuerte (yes they will be catkin) you want to use. I think it is definitely easier to upgrade your packages to catkin as the other way round.

Regards

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1